# Почему не выводится страница?

Tags: php, html

Что здесь неправильно?

```
  <?php
  if((!$_GET['cena1'] and (!$_GET['parol'] and (!$_GET['cena2'])) {
      echo "<form action=redaktNovost.php method=GET>";
      echo "<input name=parol type=password>";
      echo "<input value='&#1042;&#1074;&#1077;&#1089;&#1090;&#1080; &#1087;&#1072;&#1088;&#1086;&#1083;&#1100;' type=submit>";
      echo "</form><br><br>";
  }
  $parol = $_GET['parol'];
  $file = "parol.txt";
  $open = fopen($file, "r");
  $read = fread($open, filesize($file));
  fclose($open);
  if ($parol == $read) {
      $nov = fopen("&#1089;ena1.txt", "r+");
      @$redakt = fread($nov, filesize("cena1.txt"));
      fclose($nov);
      echo "<form action=redaktNovosti.php method=GET>";
      echo "<input name=cena1 type=text value=$redakt>";
      echo "<input type=hidden name=parol value=$parol>"
      echo "input submit value=&#1048;&#1079;&#1084;&#1077;&#1085;&#1080;&#1090;&#1100;>";
      echo "</form>";
      if(isset($_GET['cena1']));
      {
          $novosti = $_GET['cena1'];
          $data = date('d.m.Y');
          $nov = fopen("cena1.txt", "w+");
          {
              fwrite($nov, "$novosti");
          }
          fclose($nov);
      }
      {
          $nov = fopen("&#1089;ena2.txt", "r+");
          @$redakt = fread($nov, filesize("cena2.txt"));
          fclose($nov);
          echo "<form action=redaktNovosti.php method=GET>";
          echo "<input name=cena2 type=text value=$redakt>";
          echo "<input type=hidden name=parol value=$parol>"
          echo "input submit value=&#1048;&#1079;&#1084;&#1077;&#1085;&#1080;&#1090;&#1100;>";
          echo "</form>";
          if(isset($_GET['cena2']));
          {
              $novosti = $_GET['cena2'];
              $data = date('d.m.Y');
              $nov = fopen("cena2.txt", "w+");
              {
                  fwrite($nov, "$novosti");
              }
              fclose($nov);
          }
      } elseif ($parol) {
          echo "&#1053;&#1077;&#1087;&#1088;&#1072;&#1074;&#1080;&#1083;&#1100;&#1085;&#1099;&#1081; &#1087;&#1072;&#1088;&#1086;&#1083;&#1100;"
      }
  ?>
```

Comment: Используй Notepad++
Сохраняй документ в кодировке без BOM.
Проверь и отпишись. Может в этом и есть причина.
И проверь закрытость всех тегов...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Держи готовый вариант

```
  <?php
  if((!$_GET['cena1'] and (!$_GET['parol'] and (!$_GET['cena2'])))) {
      echo "<form action=redaktNovost.php method=GET>";
      echo "<input name=parol type=password>";
      echo "<input value='&#1042;&#1074;&#1077;&#1089;&#1090;&#1080; &#1087;&#1072;&#1088;&#1086;&#1083;&#1100;' type=submit>";
      echo "</form><br><br>";
  }
  $parol = $_GET['parol'];
  $file = "parol.txt";
  $open = fopen($file, "r");
  $read = fread($open, filesize($file));
  fclose($open);
  if ($parol == $read) {
      $nov = fopen("&#1089;ena1.txt", "r+");
      @$redakt = fread($nov, filesize("cena1.txt"));
      fclose($nov);
      echo "<form action=redaktNovosti.php method=GET>";
      echo "<input name=cena1 type=text value=$redakt>";
      echo "<input type=hidden name=parol value=$parol>";
     // echo "<input type ="submit" value="&#1048;&#1079;&#1084;&#1077;&#1085;&#1080;&#1090;&#1100">";
      //echo "</form>";
      if(isset($_GET['cena1']));
      {
          $novosti = $_GET['cena1'];
          $data = date('d.m.Y');
          $nov = fopen("cena1.txt", "w+");
          {
              fwrite($nov, "$novosti");
          }
          fclose($nov);
      }
      {
          $nov = fopen("&#1089;ena2.txt", "r+");
          @$redakt = fread($nov, filesize("cena2.txt"));
          fclose($nov);
          echo "<form action=redaktNovosti.php method=GET>";
          echo "<input name=cena2 type=text value=$redakt>";
          echo "<input type=hidden name=parol value=$parol>";
          echo "input submit value=&#1048;&#1079;&#1084;&#1077;&#1085;&#1080;&#1090;&#1100;>";
          echo "</form>";
          if(isset($_GET['cena2']));
          {
              $novosti = $_GET['cena2'];
              $data = date('d.m.Y');
              $nov = fopen("cena2.txt", "w+");
              {
                  fwrite($nov, "$novosti");
              }
              fclose($nov);
          }
      } 
      if ($parol) {
          echo "&#1053;&#1077;&#1087;&#1088;&#1072;&#1074;&#1080;&#1083;&#1100;&#1085;&#1099;&#1081; &#1087;&#1072;&#1088;&#1086;&#1083;&#1100";
      }}
  ?>
```

Comment: не ... не получается

Answer (score 1):

Вторая строка - затуп со скобочками. Девятнадцатая - нет точки с запятой. Дальше смотреть не стал, потому что интерпретатор php замечательно показывает ошибки - попробуйте сами.

Answer (score 1):

Во первых. Вторая строка - не все строки закрыты. Должно быть

```
if((!$_GET['cena1'] and (!$_GET['parol'] and (!$_GET['cena2'])))) {
```

Далее ругается на эти стоки

```
echo "<input type ="submit" value="&#1048;&#1079;&#1084;&#1077;&#1085;&#1080;&#1090;&#1100">";
echo "</form>";
```

Пишет ошибку

> `Parse error: parse error, unexpected T_IF, expecting ',' or ';' in w:\www\44.php on line 22`

Не знаю, что ты тут хотел сделать - в алгоритм не всматривался - некогда особо. Проверь синтаксис.